# Nginx dav: Allow to write but not to overwrite

Tags: nginx

I'm having an nginx server accepting files using PUT requests, like:

```
dav_methods PUT;
create_full_put_path on;
dav_access group:rw all:r;
```

But I'd like to only allow for "write" access, not "overwrite" access. I tried `dav_access user:r group:r all:r;`, but it will create directories without write permission, so the `create_full_put_path` is no longer working...

Even if "dav_access" would allow me to set correct right on directories and files, it looks like dav does not respect it: I created a file for root:root with mode 600, and I was allowed to overwrite it, nginx modified it to be owned by www-data:www-data and set the dav_access rights on it:

```
# ls -lah test/
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Jan 16 11:05 .
drwxr--r-- 8 www-data www-data 4.0K Jan 16 11:02 ..
-rw------- 1 root     root     2.6K Jan 16 11:05 test.py

[do the upload using curl]

# ls -lah test/
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Jan 16 11:05 .
drwxr--r-- 8 www-data www-data 4.0K Jan 16 11:02 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 2.6K Jan 16 11:05 test
```